# Can only connect to local MQ but not remote MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

My problem is that I have two servers, one running MQ Server and one running service which will get MQ messages from the former. However easily it sounds, I cannot make the latter to connect to the queue manager on the first server. I tried the following actions:

1. Ping the first server from the second one: it works just fine
2. Telnet the first server from the second one, using specific port used to connect MQ Manager on the first server (1416): it also works find
3. Now it comes the weird part: I created one Queue Manager on the second server (there is also a MQ Server running on that machine), with the same name with the MQ Manager on the first server that I want to connect, then I **can only connect to this queue**, although in the ChannelInfo I specify **exactly the first server's IP address**, not the second's.
4. After deleting the MQ Manager on the second server, it just gives me error 2058: MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR. I checked the MQ Mananer name on the first server, it was correct.
5. It is possible to connect from other servers to the first server's MQ Manager.

More information that I doubt it is the source of my problem: the first server running Windows 32 bits and the second one is running Windows 64 bits. Moreover the second one is fresh installed, so I think it might have problem with some sorts of permissions. However searching around didn't help me so far.

I really appreciate if someone here could shed some lights on my problem. It made my project overdue deadline for a week already.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No the error is not due to 32/64 bit Windows platform.

On both 32 bit as well as 64 bit Windows platforms queue manager runs as a 32 bit process.

So that's not the issue.

Obvious things to verify on the first server:

1. Have you defined a listener for the queue manager to listen on port 1416? If yes, is it running?
2. Have you defined a server connection (SVRCONN) channel on the queue manager?
3. How does your service(running on second server) attempt to connect to the queue manager? Is it bindings or client mode? In bindings mode, an application can connect only to the queue managers running on the same machine. In client mode, applications can connect to queue manager running on the same machine or a different machine.  Your service must use a client mode connection to connect to remote machine.

To connect to remote queue manager, the application must specify the host name, port and channel name.

Comment: 1. I defined a listener which listens on port 1416 and it is running.
2. I defined a server connection.
3. Actually I am not sure how to specify to use which one. I will do some research on this issue. If it works like you said, I think it is the source of my problem.

Please note that I can connect to the MQ manager on the first server  from any other machine just fine.

Comment: Does your service specify host name, port name, channel name when calling MQCONNX API? What programming language your service is developed in?

Comment: Yes, I sure did. I use C Sharp. I found that on the second machine there is no MQ Client yet. It might be the source of my problem.

Comment: oh!. But you mentioned you have MQ Server on the second machine and had queue manager running which you deleted. Did you mean you uinstalled MQ? In any case either MQ server or client is a must for applications to work.

Comment: I uninstalled MQ Server and then installed MQ Client and now my system is working!